# How can I use other behaviors with yii2-nested-set-behavior?

Tags: php, nested-lists, yii2

I have model Category. I use yii2-nested-set-behavior. I want to use SluggableBehavior, but I can't to do it, because yii2-nested-set-behavior does not allow the use of afterSave and beforeSave. 
How to solve this problem ?? How can I use other behaviors with yii2-nested-set-behavior??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package yii2-nested-set-behavior was written for Yii 2 beta. Use https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets since its complete overhaul for Yii 2 release and compatible with any other behaviors.